# Consultas con Tinker, ¿cómo mostrar el SQL?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, tinker

Estoy haciendo **pruebas con Laravel / Tinker**, he observado que cuando no tiene acceso a la BD imprime la consulta SQL en lugar del resultado de la misma, p.e. la consulta *Eloquent*:

```
User::first();
```

Devuelve el primer usuario si puede conectarse a la BD (y lo encuentra), y la query SQL en caso contrario (después de un mensaje de error SQLSTATE):

```
(SQL: select * from `users` limit 1)'
```

¿Hay alguna forma de imprimir las consultas SQL de forma habitual, sin tener que forzar el error de conexión, usando un parámetro o configuración adicional?

***NOTA***: sin usar "query log" de Eloquent.

Comment: Has probado a poner `->toSql()` en lugar de `->get()` o similares?

Comment: @Manuel Robles `->toSql()` me vale, gracias. Sustituye a `->get()` o `->first()` en su caso. Aunque si hay una pequeña diferencia con obtener el error (la consulta aparece con los parámetros en este caso) o usar el *query log* (este muestra más info, como los parámetros pasados o el tiempo de ejecución). Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Prueba intentar ejecutar esto en la consola del thinker

```
DB::listen(function ($query) { dump($query->sql); dump($query->bindings); dump($query->time); });
```

Para que luego de cada consulta te muestre el **SQL**, los **parámetros** recibidos y el **tiempo** total de ejecución

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias es otra opción, similar al query log.
Un saludo.